# How can I de-associate my Stack Overflow profile from other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, accounts

I have the Stack Exchange profile which shows links to all the Stack Exchange sites.

Now I have to send my Stack Overflow profile to my employer.

But I only want to show them my Stack Overflow profile. I have asked some questions regarding employment and resumes on other Stack Exchange sites which I don't want them to see.

Is there a way to make my profile only show Stack Overflow and not any other profile?

Comment: Technically, it *ought to* be possible for SE staff to transfer all posts and comments on one site (e.g. SO) from one account to another, so, in principle, you could create a new account on SO (with a different OpenID) and ask to have your posts transferred to it. I have no idea whether or under what circumstances they'd actually do that, but I don't think there's really anything you could lose by asking.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm pretty sure they won't do that.  They stopped permitting users to delete and then recreate their accounts and this sounds like roughly the same idea.

Comment: You _have_ to send it to your employer? Why? Personally, I'd tell them to take a hike.

Comment: If you're in the US and they see those other posts, I believe that constitutes discrimination. Not sure though.

Comment: @Qix: Obviously I can't speak for every other country in the world, but in the UK that constitutes _taking the piss_. What right does any employer have to demand any online profile from an employee?

Comment: @TheBlueDog None, I'm agreeing with you. I'm saying it's *illegal* for an employer to reject an applicant based on things like this in the US, I believe.

Comment: @qix: Sorry, I was actually agreeing with you too, even if it didn't come across that way. Should have phrased it better.

Comment: Err, "I don't have any." ? Problem solved. And to be honest, I wouldn't show them your account. You're showing quite weak problem description skills in your questions... Show them this meta question :-)

Comment: @TLama - I assume this isn't the main account as there are no questions about resumes etc on anything linked.

Comment: @Qix: *discrimination*? I doubt that "people asking questions about employment on SO" qualifies as a class of people, particular a protected one. While this might just fly against some other law (doubt it), practically speaking if they don't hand you a signed letter saying you weren't taken because of that.. good luck. Now nobody can force you to hand over a SO account anyhow (I heard not everybody has one to begin with).

Comment: @Voo you're completely missing my point....

Comment: @Qix Nothing mentioned anywhere in the question has anything to do with discrimination, so why bring that up then? Sorry, but it's a pet-peeve of mine that people throw that word around without actually considering its meaning. I mean yes in the widest sense of the word, you can discriminate against the "group of people that ask questions on SO", but that's perfectly legal.

Comment: @Voo, no, inquiring about personal habits and such can be considered discrimination in some parts of the United States. Under certain state law an employer cannot inquire about past employment or reject applicants based on such. The OP is asking about workplace-related posts, which *could* potentially fall under that scope. I'm not here to discuss your personal qualms with the word *discrimination*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

You can see more details in [Kevin Montrosse's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109054/182513) to [How can I disassociate an account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109044/how-can-i-disassociate-an-account) on Meta.SE.  But in short, logins and accounts are managed at the network level and it is impossible to separate the accounts from each other.

There are 2 possible solutions depending how many questions & answers you are concerned about.

1. If you have a number of posts you are concerned about, the nuclear option is to delete the accounts you want to disassociate and create new accounts on those sites with a different login.  As long as you completely sign out before creating the new account use a different login, your new account should be completely separate.  You would lose all your rep and all your privileges and would no longer own your old posts, but at least they would be separate.  To see how to delete your account, check out [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)
2. You can request specific posts be disassociated from your account.  You would lose any rep you gained from those specific posts and you would no longer own those posts, but at least you wouldn't be starting from scratch.  Too see how to disassociate posts, you can read [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki).  I would caution you that if you do this, you should only do this for a couple of posts.  If you ask to have a majority of your posts disassociated, the SE team is likely to recommend you delete your account instead.

There have been feature requests, such as [Allow users to hide connections between accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts), to allow users to hide accounts or have "private" associations so users can maintain some anonymity on specific sites, but they have yet to be implemented.

Comment: It would be very nice to be able to make *some* posts anonymous but without losing track of them and without losing reputation contributions. (basically, they must appear as anonymous to everyone except the author) Managing multiple accounts is not cool

Comment: @SargeBorsch eh, I'm not sure I like that idea.  Part of the benefit of the sites is the community moderation and that would be impossible if someone were to be able to post anonymously but still gain all of the benefits.  The ideal solution is to let users hide connections between accounts so if you are looking at my SO profile, you will not see that I have an account on Cooking.SE (if that is my desire).

Comment: Just make it so an anonymous post can not receive positive rep gains, but can only receive negative rep. If someone is going to be a jerk, they can already do so with impunity by creating another account.

Comment: @woot the problem is identifying the jerk.  If the posts are anonymous, no one will be able to figure out if it is the same jerk or 20 different ones.  I don't think there is a need for anonymous posts.  If there is really that much of a need to post something that isn't tied to your main account, then you can create another account

Comment: This only shows for me that the SE can't be trusted. No one warns anybody that he won't be able to ever detach/retract his posts/accounts any more.